# htaccess for subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm new htaccess. So i need to rewrite .php to .html in url.

my files located in

`http://www.domain.us/sub1/sub2/sub2/index.php`

I need to rewrite as 
`http://www.domain.us/sub1/sub2/sub2/index.html.`

I tried something

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} site 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ http://www.domain.us/sub1/sub2/sub3/$1.html [R,L]
```

But It shows `404 error`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your DOCUMENT_ROOT's .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/*sub1/sub2/sub2/.*\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1.html [NC,NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: It rewrite the url but www.domain.us/index.html. I need to rewrite in same folder. That's http://www.domain.us/sub1/sub2/sub2/index.html.

Comment: As per your questions you want to rwrite `/sub1/sub2/sub2/foo.php` to `/sub1/sub2/sub2/foo.html`? Is that not right?